# Adding a new calculated row to an existing pandas dataframe with calculations specific to each column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to add a new row to an existing dataframe that consists of values calculated from the pre existing rows.
My input looks something like this:

| name | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | 10 | 30 | 40 | 50 |
| mary | 50 | 10 | 30 | 20 |
| smith | 40 | 20 | 40 | 10 |

Now I want to add a Grand total row at the end but the row must not only hold the sum value.
Something like this:

| name | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Grand total | (sum)100 | sum(60) | (value2.sum/value1.sum)0.6 | (avg ) |

Thanks in advance

Comment: avg is from column4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) and add another values to `Series`, last add new row in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
s = df.agg({'value1':'sum', 'value2':'sum', 'value4':'mean'})
s['name'] = 'Grand total'
s['value3'] = s['value2'] / s['value1']

df.loc[len(df)] = s
```

Or processing separately:

```
s = df[['value1','value2']].sum()
s['name'] = 'Grand total'
s['value3'] = s['value2'] / s['value1']
s['value4'] = df['value4'].mean()

df.loc[len(df)] = s
print (df)
          name  value1  value2  value3     value4
0         john      10      30    40.0  50.000000
1         mary      50      10    30.0  20.000000
2        smith      40      20    40.0  10.000000
3  Grand total     100      60     0.6  26.666667
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jezrael, this solved my problem.